# Intel HDI Sound (ThinkPad X60) not working without display manager

Tags: fedora, audio, intel

My sound works out of the box under Fedora 20 as long as I use lightdm. But I don't want to use any display manager -- if I use X, I start dwm manually. Unfortunately, the Intel HDI driver (Model AD1981) doesn't seem to be loaded in the latter case as it is not presented as an option as it is when I go through lightdm. Can anyone tell me how to manually load it or what else I need to do to (under Fedora 20)?

Thanks!